# Smartface Creating an iOS plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, command-line-interface, smartface.io

I've installed the CLI tools.
Now what do you do in order to make a plugin.

I've tried looking at the guides however I can't figure out exactly what to do?
I'm also puzzled as to where you create the plugin whether It's on The Command Prompt or Node.js or the Smartface Studio itself.

Answer (score 0):

To create a plugin, you need native environment from the system. In your case, XCode.

My reccomendation to learn plugins is this tutorial by Smartface Team: https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/hello-world-with-ios-plugin/

This is the most basic plugin you could write, but it still shows the fundamentals of plugin writing for Smartface.

P.S. You will need a Mac to develop iOS plugins (just to be sure that you know that).

Hope that helps! :)

**EDIT**

I was revisiting this question and I realized that I was very vague...

To answer your question, you have to develop your plugin in Native Environment (as I said), and when you build it's package, you have to put it in the same directory of the other files you'll need (PluginConfig and all of that), and run, in command prompt, the command to make the output.zip file.

Now it's better :)